# Update or insert a mysql database with 60 million entries

Tags: mysql, database, optimization

I have a mysql database which has a table with around 60 million entries with primary key say 'x'. I have a data set(csv file) which also has around 60 million entries. This dataset also has index 'x'.  For values of key 'x' common to both the mysql table and dataset, the corresponding entries in the mysql table just gets updated with increment to a counter variable. The new ones in the dataset are to be inserted.

A simple serial execution in which we try to update the entry if present or else insert takes around 8 hours to complete. What can I do to increase the speed of this whole procedure?

Comment: `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Comment: What do you mean by _dataset_? A CSV file? A database doesn't have entries, but a table in a database does. Your terminology is unclear.

Comment: yes dataset is a csv file. By database I mean table in database.

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  IODKU, as @Rogue suggested.

Plan B:  Two sqls; they might run faster because part of the 8 hours is gathering a huge amount of undo information in case of a crash.  The [*normalization section*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization) comes close to those 2 queries.

Plan C:  Walk through the pair of tables, using the `PRIMARY KEY` of one of them to do IODKU in chunks of, say, 1000 rows.  See my [*Chunking*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks) code (and adapt it from `DELETE` to `IODKU`).

In Plans B and C, turn on `autocommit` so that you don't build up a huge redo log.

Plan D:  Build a new table as you merge the two tables with a `JOIN`.  Finish with an atomic

```
RENAME TABLE real TO old,
             new TO real;
DROP TABLE old;   -- when happy with the result.
```

Plan E:  Plan D + Chunking of the `INSERT ... SELECT real JOIN tmp ...`

Comment: Thanks. Let me try some of these and see what efficiency I get.